# C# OLEDB join two tables from two connections

Tags: c#, join, oledb

In OLEDB , is it possible to left join query for two tables from two connections

as instance , import two excel workbooks with the following columns :

table1 : Names (string)

table2 : Names (string) , Nums (int)

it's simple to query one table
but  I stuck when tried to left join the two tables , because each one of them
have it's own connection .

Comment: In a word; no.. But feel free to pull all the data into a c# datatable and left join it there, for example. You might be better off inserting both excel files into a sqlserver instance if it's a lot or regular

Comment: Forgive me for maybe a silly question , is that mean I need to use Sql Server ?

Comment: Not necessarily; it was just a "can" - and I suspect that you could also link your SQLs to each of the excel files and then get it to do the join; loads of ways to skin the cat